# Automatic scrollViewer

Tags: c#, windows, scrollviewer

How can I do automatic movement of a ScrollViewer?. I need that when he moves a bit, scroll down to the end, and the reverse also, when at the end and moves a bit, scroll down to the start. I've done tests with ViewChanged event, but a stranger make movements that are unpleasant for the user.

Comment: `but a stranger make movements that are unpleasant for the user` what?

Comment: He had put: ScrollToHorizontalOffset (svShiPay.ScrollableWidth), to reach the end, and if it was in the final ScrollToHorizontalOffset (0), but to put the 2 under an if condition inside the ScrollViewer ViewChanged event is creating a shake movement to the end . It is also a very sudden movement and is not nice.